# How do you scan inputs for specific substrings in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, substring

I am new to coding and python and am trying to code a simple calculator for multiplication, division, addition, and subtraction. I already have two separate ones for addition/subtraction and multiplication/division. I have no real reason to build these other than pure practice. I am trying to build a block which detects whether the user has inputted '*', '/', '+', or '-' for their respective operations. However, I cannot figure out how to do so with if statements. Also, I need to code it so that if the user inputs anything besides '*', '/', '+', or '-', that it will loop it back to where it asked for them to input one of those operators in the first place.

UPDATE:
I figured out how to do so, except it seems bigger than it needs to be, here is the block of code I wrote for it:

```
       while True:
            operator = input("What would you like to do? *, /, -, + : ")
            if operator == '*':
                break;
            elif operator == '/':
                break;
            elif operator == '+':
                break;
            elif operator == '-':
                break;
            else:
                print("Please enter '*', for multiplication, '/' for division, '+' for addition, or '-' for subtraction.")
```

Comment: Try learning if-else statements

Comment: There is a subtle contradiction between "I have no real reason to build these other than pure practice" and "I need to code it so that ...". The former suggests that this is a hobby project, the latter suggests that this is a homework assignment which must satisfy some specification.

Comment: @JohnColeman perhaps it's a textbook or some sort of self-paced course which OP is self-studying from? But yes, either way some example code would be nice

Comment: @JohnColeman sometimes practicing hobbies is good, like if you play a sport, practicing it is important to get better. That's what this project is.

Comment: I was being pedantic -- but there is a difference between what you *want* a project to do and what you *need* a project to do -- and you seemed to be equivocating between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I have here tried out a different perspective to getting your calculator. mixture of some concepts you might find interesting

```
import operator


operation ={
   '-'  : operator.sub,
   '/' : operator.truediv,
  '*'   : operator.mul,
    '+' : operator.add
}
while True:
    inp1= int(input('enter you number: '))
    inp2= int(input('enter you number: '))
    oper= input('what operation: ')

    if oper in operation:  # <--checks it for validity of the operation
        print(operation[oper](inp1,inp2)) 
        
        break
    else:  #<--- if operation is invalid it continues the loop
        continue
```

Comment: Thank you for the informational response, this helped!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with for fun, and it actually is not far from Ade_1's answer ;-)

```
import operator
import sys


operations = {
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv,
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub
}


def valid_input():
    val = input()
    try:
        return int(val)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(val)
        except ValueError:
            print('must be an integer or a float')
            sys.exit(-1)


res = valid_input()
while True:
    op = input()
    if op not in operations:
        break
    
    other = valid_input()
    res = operations[op](res, other)
    print(res)
    
print('bye')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help on this

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to check with an if-statement. Here I put the if-statement inside a while loop so the code keeps asking the user to input an operation until one of the `* / - +` has be inputted:

```
operation = ''

while True:
    a = input('Enter a mathematical operation: ')
    if a in ['/', '*', '-', '+']:
        operation = a
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this information helped me with this a lot.

Comment: as a rule of thumb, I never ever use `eval`

Comment: @DevLounge is it for security concerns? How about `eval(repr(SomeClassInstance))`?